# The largest value of $n$ such that $n+10| n^3+100$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and follow the property

$$n+10| n^3+100$$

then what is the largest value of $n$

Please help me to solve this!!!

Comment: Hint:  $(n+10)(n^2 - 10n + 100)$ is pretty close to $n^3 + 100$.  How can $n+10$ divide both of these?

Comment: Hint: Alternatively worded to ravi's hint, $n^3+100=n^3+10n^2-10n^2-100n+100n+1000-1000+100$

Comment: problems like these almost always fall to the euclidean algorithm on both polynomials

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $m=n+10$ then $n=m-10$ $$n^3+100=(m-10)^3+100$$ $$=m^3-30m^2+300m-900$$
condition $$(n+10)|(n^3+100)$$ now takes the form $$m|(m^3-30m^2-300m-900)$$
Since $m$ is divisor of each of the quantities $m^3,30m^2,300m$

It follows that $$m|900$$ The largest $m$ for which this is true is $m=900$, so it follows that the largest $n$ with the given property is $$n=890$$

Comment: I like how this is systematic, without needing to appeal to memory to remember some expansions

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
n+10|n^3+10n^2\implies n+10|(n^3+10n^2)-(n^3+100)=10n^2-100.
$$
Similarly,
\begin{aligned}
&\quad n+10|(10n^2+100n)-(10n^2-100)=100n+100\\
&\implies n+10|(100n+1000)-(100n+100)=900.
\end{aligned}
So the largest possible $n$ is $900-10=\boxed{890}$. Verify that this works:
$$
\frac{890^3+100}{890+10}=783299\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that: $n+10| n^3+100$ is same as $$n+10| n^3+1000-900$$
$$\implies n+10| (n^3+1000)-900$$

$$\implies n+10| (n+10)(n^2-10n+100)-900\implies n+10|900$$.

The greatest integer dividing $900$ is $900$ itself. So, for maximum $n$, $$n+10=900\implies n=900-10=890$$

Comment: Yup, +1 for nice solution :)